# AWS Lambda and S3 - uploaded pdf file is blank/corrupt

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Spring App (running on AWS Lambda) that gets a file and uploads it on AWS S3.

The Spring Controller sends a `MultipartFile` to my method, where it's uploaded to AWS S3, using Amazon API Gateway.

```
public static void uploadFile(MultipartFile mpFile, String fileName) throws IOException{

    String dirPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/tmp");
    File file = new File(dirPath  + "/" + fileName);

    OutputStream ops = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ops.write(mpFile.getBytes());

    s3client.putObject("fakebucketname", fileName, file);

}
```

I try to upload a PDF file which has 2 pages with text. After upload, the PDF file(on AWS S3) has 2 blank pages.

Why is the uploaded PDF file blank?

I also tried with other files(like PNG image) and when I open it the image I uploaded is corrupted.

The only thing that worked was when I uploaded a text file.

Comment: Why aren't you closing the output stream before you attempt to upload the file to S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this will do this trick. Its all about encoding, thanks to the help of @KunLun. In my scenario, file is the multipart file (pdf) that is passed to aws via a POST to the url.

- server gets a file with this byte -> 0010 (this will not be
  interpreted right, because a standard byte has 8 bits)
- so, we encode it in base 64 -> doesn't matter what result
- decode it to get a standard byte -> 0000 0010 (now this is a standard byte and it's interpreted right by aws)
- This source here helped a lot as well -->
  https://www.javaworld.com/article/3240006/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-java-8.html?page=2

```
        Base64.Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
        byte[] encbytes = enc.encode(file.getBytes());
        for (int i = 0; i < encbytes.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%c", (char) encbytes[i]);
            if (i != 0 && i % 4 == 0)
                System.out.print(' ');
        }
        Base64.Decoder dec = Base64.getDecoder();
        byte[] barray2 = dec.decode(encbytes);
        InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(barray2);

        PutObjectResult objectResult = s3client.putObject("xxx", file.getOriginalFilename(), fis, data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I say I have seen people do this allot, whereby their app, accepts a MultipartFile, and proxy upload it to S3.

Uploading to your App and then S3 honestly is the wrong approach, and has many drawbacks which negate the benefits of using S3 in the first place. Simply generate a pre-signed URL and have your user upload directly to S3. This is preferable for a few reasons but the main ones are:

- An app which acepts MultipartFile upload can be easily DDOS'ed if not careful, this happened to our app when somebody uploaded many files at the same time whole system went down.
- It will be MUCH slower to upload to your backend app and then upload to S3.

If you happened to be using Cognito you can also achieve this with 0 backend code using AWS Amplify. Which I highly recommend, but if not then pre-signed URL is the way to go.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by generate a pre signed url? If we’re using a Java spring app our client is going to need to post the pdf form at some sort of api url, are you talking about an implementation similar to this? Please elaborate the work flow you’re thinking of here with this in mind: the client will have to post the pdf form somewhere, it will then get manipulated, and then the new manipulated form will be need to be displayed via a redirect using spring

Comment: Basically you can tell S3, hey give me a temporary  URL to upload a file, and then give that to the user to upload. Once they have uploaded you can then manipulate it.

Comment: that does not seem like a very viable option to have built within an application. Could you please elaborate? Could this temp url be re created for each client that wants to submit a form?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by viable in this context, but anyway what you are doing is `user -> upload to app -> upload to s3` but you can do `app gives URL to user` then `user -> upload to s3`. I suggest you at least try the AWS way first before you decide it is not viable, just find a tutorial somewhere, language doesn't matter just get the concept down https://github.com/jkahn117/aws-presigned-url-upload

Comment: this does not tell us how to upload a file. Tells us how to upload a string that has been written to an output stream. Could you clarify how one would write an entire pdf to s3 with a similar methodology?

Comment: @Snickers3192 is right: you should use an S3 pre-signed url. The example linked above shows how to generate a URL that has "PutObject" permissions, then you use an HTTP PUT request with the pre-signed URL to upload the file, e.g. PDF, to the S3 object specified. There is a Java example in the AWS S3 documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObjectJavaSDK.html