# unable to upload pdf containing only images to S3 bucket using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I've images which have been converted into pdf and stored in a folder named 'test'.

I need to upload all files inside test folder to S3

Current situation : files get created in S3 but are empty. I'm assuming because the source pdf file only contains an image. I'm unable to figure out a way to ensure images of the pdf also get uploaded

Here's my code:

```
import os
import boto3
import botocore
import sys

SERVICE_NAME = 's3'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXX+A'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'resolution-medical/resolution_scanner'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'resolution-medical'

source_folder = '/home/irfan/Downloads/test'

arr = os.listdir(source_folder)

for each in arr:
    try:
        arr2 = os.listdir(source_folder + '/' + each)
    except:
        arr2 = []

    if len(arr2) == 0:
        filepath = 'resolution_scanner/' + each
        fileobject = source_folder+ '/' + each

        conn = boto3.resource(
        service_name=SERVICE_NAME,
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        endpoint_url=AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL)
        conn.Object(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, filepath).put(Body=fileobject, ACL='public-read', ContentType='application/pdf')

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the encoding issue occurs with `put()`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310267/aws-lambda-and-s3-uploaded-pdf-file-is-blank) SO Q&A solving with java. For me, just using `upload_file()` works like this:

```
import boto3

file = "PDF/aaaaa.pdf"

s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
s3.Object("my-bucket-test", "test.pdf").upload_file(file)
```